# update data table after save button

Tags: datatable

in form load this code :
   //datatable of navigation buttons first last next previous //
            da = new SqlDataAdapter("select Code,Saved,Name,ShortName,DFCurrency,Rate,SmallCurrency,ShortSmallName from Currency order by Code+1 desc", conn);
            da.Fill(dt);
           if (dt.Rows.Count > 0 && dt.Rows[0][0] != DBNull.Value)
           {
                showdata(pos);
           }
 public void showdata(int index)
        {

```
        code_txt.Text = dt.Rows[index][0].ToString();
        saved_check.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(dt.Rows[index][1]);
        name_txt.Text = dt.Rows[index][2].ToString();
        shortname_txt.Text = dt.Rows[index][3].ToString();
        defcurrency_check.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(dt.Rows[index][4]);
        rate_txt.Text = dt.Rows[index][5].ToString();
        smallcurrency_text.Text = dt.Rows[index][6].ToString();
        shortsmall_txt.Text = dt.Rows[index][7].ToString();
    }
```

i need to update data table rows after save button .